# How To Make an Image Appear in the Center of the Browser Window When the Cursor Hovers Atop A Different Image

Tags: html, css

[UPDATE: Use position "fixed" works!]

THE GOAL:
The goal entails making an image appear in the center of the browser window, when the cursor hovers atop a different image.

PRESENT STATUS: 
The present status (ref. code below) exhibits successfully causing an image to appear when the cusrsor hovers atop a different image.  However, multiple attempts involving manipulating the CSS have failed to make the image always appear in the center of the browser window.  An image does appear.  The location of the appearance; however, does not always occur in the center of the browser window.

Note that the CSS "relative" feature has been used, but the result involves the image appearing in different locations, depending upon which image the cursor hover occurs.  The idea - the goal - is to have the appearing images always appear in the center of the browser window, regardless of which image in the table the cursor is hovering upon.

HERE IS THE RELEVANT CSS AND XHTML:

```css
.appear span {
  display: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
 
.appear:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 500px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 544px;
  height: 306px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.pic_matrix { 
   clear: both;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   border: none;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.pics { 
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   width: 180px; 
   height: auto;    
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
   <table class="pic_matrix">
      <tr>
      <td class="pics">Title 1</td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="001_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="001_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="002_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="002_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="003_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="003_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="004_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="004_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="pics">Title 2</td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="005_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="005_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="006_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="006_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="007_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="007_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="008_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="008_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="pics">Title 3</td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="009_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="009_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="010_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="010_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="011_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="011_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      <td class="pics"><a class="appear" href=""><img src="012_small.jpg" width="80" height="100" alt="" /><span><img src="012_big.jpg" width="544" height="306" /></span></a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your problem, then you need to just modify your css class properties to this,

```css
.appear:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -272px 0px 0px -153px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 544px;
  height: 306px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, the top and left properties are set to 50% and the margin-top and margin-left values are set to negative of half of height of the image and negative of half of width of the image repectively...
margin-top = -(height_of_image/2),
margin-left = -(width_of_image/2)

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect is accomplished via pure CSS using the combination of the "position: fixed;" concept mentioned earlier in the original post's [update], and the negative margin concept suggested by "user3687099".

Thank you for your suggestion!